# Fix error on why my JSF application freezes

Tags: jsf-2

Please I need your help on the issue below, My jsf application freezes after 3 times of clicking the command button. I don't seem to know why that happens, and I dont know where the error is coming from, I had to restart tomcat before the application starts, Below is my code;

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <b:container>
        <div style="height: 15px" />
            <h:form id="job-main-form"  class="job-main-form">
                <div class="controls">
                  <div class="row">

                      <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <b:inputText id="e_qualificationToBeAwarded" 
                                    value="#{job.searchTerm}"     placeholder="Profession you are looking for"
                                    maxlength="255" styleClass="ui-fluid"     />
                      </div> 
                      <div class="col-lg-3">  
                          <b:commandButton type="submit" value=""
                                         action="#{job.seachJobs}" 
                                         iconAwesome="search" id="btn"
                                         class="btn btn-primary" />
                      </div>



                      <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{job.listOfJobs}" var="item"
                                      selectionMode="single" selection="#{job.jobs}" reflow="true"
                                      paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                      rowKey="#{item.id}"
                                      rows="10"
                                      rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50"
                                      >


                              <p:column width="200" >
                                  <f:facet name="header">
                                      <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                                  </f:facet>
                                  <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
                              </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </h:form>
    </b:container>
 </h:body>
```

and my bean method is

```
public void seachJobs(){
        listOfJobs = commonsession.getJobsByName(searchTerm);

}
```

Comment: What, regarding generic web development debugging, did you investigate? You now sort of ask if we remotely can investigate why your car is not driving when you yourself are a car mechanic

Comment: Suspicion: connection pool problems to a database

Comment: @Kukeltje, please no error comes up, I have no idea how to debug it, cos on the click of the command button code executes fine but not on the third click. Please direct me to any debugging tool I can use to fix the issue

Comment: Both your browser and IDE have debugging tools, I hope you know this when you do webdevelopment in java.